# Show the site name in a custom block

Tags: blocks

I am working on Drupal 8 custom block. I want to print the site name in this custom block.

#### MyBlock.php

```php
public function build() {
  return [
    '#markup' => t('This is a simple block!'),
  ];
}
```

How can I get the site name?

Answer (score 5):

Get the site name from config and add the config as cacheable dependency so that the block gets updated when you change the site name.

```
public function build() {
  $config = \Drupal::config('system.site');

  $build = [
    '#markup' => $config->get('name'),
  ];

  $renderer = \Drupal::service('renderer');
  $renderer->addCacheableDependency($build, $config);

  return $build;
}
```

Comment: Did not know you could add config as cacheable dependency. Nice!